# how to select custom dropdown list element from selenium

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver

how to select custom dropdown list element from selenium.

I want to select a country from the dropdown list, using selenium python webdrive.

```
<select id="id_country" class="hidden-field" name="country" data-id="1394114974464-fOg4n">
<div class="custom dropdown" data-id="1394114974464-fOg4n">
<a class="current" href="#">Belize</a>
<a class="selector" href="#"></a>
<ul>
<li class="">Select Your Country</li>
<li class="">Afghanistan</li>
<li>Albania</li>
<li class="">Algeria</li>
<li class="">American Samoa</li>
<li class="">Andorra</li>
<li>Angola</li>
<li class="">Anguilla</li>
<li class="">Antigua and Barbuda</li>
<li class="">Argentina</li>
<li class="">Armenia</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [currently recommended method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) of selecting an item from a dropdown menu is to use the Select class. Here's a quick example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("file:///C:\testing\\test.html")

element = browser.find_element_by_id("id_country")
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text("Armenia")
```

However, the HTML you posted doesn't seem to work; I just get an empty dropdown box. You'll need to fix that in order to be able to use the above code. For example:

```
<html><body>
<select id="id_country" name="country">
<option>Select Your Country</option>
<option>Afghanistan</option>
<option>Armenia</option>
</select>
</body></html>
```

This works fine for me, producing a dropdown box with three options - `Select Your Country`, `Afghanistan` and `Armenia`. Pointing the above Python script at this file correctly selects `Armenia`.

Edit: Here's a quick-and-dirty Python script that successfully selects Armenia from the list of countries:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://ds.arm.com/rfq/")

country = "Armenia"

dropdown_path = "id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/a[2]"
country_path = "id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/ul/li[contains(text(), '%s')]" % country

browser.find_element_by_xpath(dropdown_path).click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(country_path).click()
```

It makes use of XPaths to locate the dropdown arrow and then the `<li>` tag containing "Armenia". I don't claim that it's especially intuitive, or neat to look at, but it works. They've really over-complicated things with that website, so I'm not sure if the simpler `Select` method can be made to work here. In general, if you can locate an element using an id (`find_element_by_id`), class (`find_element_by_class`) or name (`find_element_by_name`), you should do so. None of those work here, unfortunately :)

I can recommend the [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) extension for Firefox to help you find similar XPaths for the other form elements. Good luck, I really don't envy you having to work with that site!!

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply. I am getting error ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:. This may be because "select id="id_country" class="hidden-field" name="country"

Comment: I've added some modified HTML to my answer, which uses the `<option>` tag to populate the dropdown menu. I've also updated the Python script to point at a file containing this HTML, and it works well enough for me. Can you try it and see what happens?

Comment: Hi, I cant modify the HTML code, I dont have permission to do so. I am trying to learn selenium and trying to automate the page "http://ds.arm.com/rfq/" by selecting different countries in the list.

Comment: Ah. Not entirely sure what sort of magic is going on there, but okay. I think you're going to have to do it manually, by clicking on the dropdown arrow (with class `selector`), then clicking on the `<li>` element that contains the text you want.

Comment: I really appreciate for looking into this issue. Can you please provie me a working python script. I am very new to HTML.

Comment: Added a script in. It's not exactly my greatest work, I'm afraid, but it does the job.

Comment: great it is almost working now, but some how fails to substitute the variable value(country), what am I doing wrong.                        {  from selenium import webdriver browser = webdriver.Firefox() browser.get("ds.arm.com/rfq/") country="Armenia" browser.find_element_by_xpath("id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/a[2‌​]").click() browser.find_element_by_xpath("id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/ul/‌​li[contains(text(), country)]") }

Comment: The `find_element_by_xpath` method returns a `WebElement` which you then need to call `.click()` on in order to actually click it. Looks like you haven't called `.click()` on the element containing `country`.

Comment: sorry copy paste error may actual code is { from selenium import webdriver browser = webdriver.Firefox() browser.get("ds.arm.com/rfq/") country="Armenia" browser.find_element_by_xpath("id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/a[2‌​‌​]").click() browser.find_element_by_xpath("id('content')/form/fieldset/div[5]/div[2]/div/ul/‌​‌​li[contains(text(), country)]").click }  This code is not working, it fails to select country "Armenia".

Comment: Either another copy-paste error, or you've missed out the brackets after `.click` ;) I'm at work right now so can't really look into it properly, but what happens when you run it? Does it at least cause the dropdown box to open? Do any error messages appear?

Comment: It does cause the dropdown box to open. and fails to select any element from dropdown menu and silently collapses and takes default value. No error is reported.

Comment: Can you please look into this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I was away from the computer over the weekend. Now that I'm somewhat more alert than I was Friday afternoon, I can see the problem with your code - you've got `country` inside the XPath, so it's looking for the option called `country` rather than using the variable `country`! I'll update the script again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, will wait for your updated script :-)

Comment: works perfectly fine thank you very much. Can you please suggest some books or webpages for me to understand selenium, python and HTML basic.

Comment: For Python, the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/) is very good for getting started. Plenty of great resources exist for HTML, a simple Google search should get you started there. As for Selenium, I'm fairly new myself and have gotten by trawling Google and Stack Overflow for solutions, basically making it up as I go along. There has been a lot of experimentation, much of it a complete failure, but that's how you learn!